# $Sing(X)$ is a discrete set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Friends, can you help me?

Let $X\in C^1(U)$, with $U$ open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. If every singularity of $X$  is hyperbolic, show that $Sing(X)$ (the set of singularities of $X$) is a discrete set.

Comment: what is $Sing$?

Comment: Set of singularities.

Comment: What is meant with a singularity being hyperbolic?